# What is the best way to get NGRX data from multiple slices of the store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Is there a best practice for getting data from multiple slices of an NGRX store?  I'm using NGRX entity and I have a slice for companies, users, vendors, and orders and in a particular component, I need to access all 4.  I've tried a few different methods but they all seem cumbersome.

Should I use 4 separate selectors from multiple entities or is it better to make a selector at the root level and include everything needed for the details page?

Currently, I'm using a `combineLatest` operator

```js
this.subscription.add(this.store.select(fromUser.getUsers).pipe(
    combineLatest([
        this.store.select(fromCompanies.selectAll),
        this.store.select(fromVendors.selectAll),
        this.store.select(fromOrders.getOrders),
    ]))
```

Comment: I understand and I’m using selectors. I was just curious if I need slices of state from multiple entities if I should use 4 different selectors or create a single root level selector with the specific data I need

Comment: If the data composed from 4 selectors is used by multiple features of your app then have a single selector, at root level, which projects the resulted data from 4 selectors. If same data is used only by one component then whatever you did is correct.

Comment: got it, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find the best way to combine selectors is by using selectors, this will also be the most performant way because NgRx does some optimization here.

A `createSelector` can be composed from multiple selectors, in your case this would be:

```
export const foo = createSelector(
  fromUser.getUsers,
  fromCompanies.selectAll,
  fromVendors.selectAll,
  fromOrders.getOrders,
  (users, companies, vendors, orders) => {
     // logic here
  }
)
```

For more info see [Sharing data between modules is peanuts](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/sharing-data-between-modules-is-peanuts)

Comment: So would it be a bad idea to just have a selector for each component and then just load in everything you'd need for that component?

Comment: No I usually do the same thing

Comment: in such a case @timdeschryver, would you put this selector in (around) your component directly or around the store files?

Comment: I've seen both @smad, and I think it's about personal preference. Personally, if it's just used within the component I'd like to have that selector closer to the component. Bing consistent is the key here.